# Is it possible to make sencha touch 2.0 list component to have its items expandable?

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2

I have a list component which is filled out using a data store(data loaded from server as json). A part of data from data store is displayed as list items, and i need some kind of a "+" button to the left of it to expand a list item(and "-" to collapse) to reveal(/hide) the remaining info. I could simply put some javascript to itemTpl tag but i've no idea how to make smooth transitions this way. Maybe am missing some standard settings for a list component, but i can't find any info. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard settings to do this functionality. But this is possible to achieve. You can have your item template as something like this:

```
itemTpl: '<div class="plus"></div><div class="title">{title}</div><div class="hidden">{mydetails}</div>'
```

Initially, the details is hidden. You need to handle the animation when your taps the list item. So, in your event you will have to do:

```
itemtap: function(view,index,htmlElement,e,opts) {

    // change the div plus to minu..
    // Get hold of the div with details class and animate
    var el = htmlElement.select('div[class=hidden]');

    el.toggleCls('hidden'); //remove the hidden class if available..
    el.show(true); // show with animation
```

}

The object is obtained from `select()` method is `Ext.dom.CompositeElementLite` .. Refer this class for more methods. You can call the `Ext.Anim` from this object as well..

To animate you can use the `Ext.Anim` class. Once you have the html element of you 'details' div, you can:

```
Ext.Anim.run(detailsDiv,'slide',{
    out:false,
    from: 'hiddenCSS',
    to: 'visibleCSS'
});
```

Refer to [Anim](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Anim) class for more setting that might be needed to have your desired effect. Also note that you will have to track the previously clicked (expanded) list items.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it's great! However i can't get the html element of 'details' div. I believe am doing smth wrong, im trying to do it as follows: 'itemtap':function(list, index, item, evt){/*...*/ var details = item.dom.getElementsByClassName('details')[0];  details.className += " show"; /*...*/} This code does show details but i have to remove the show class myself, and i can't use details.addCls since it's not a sencha touch element. I believe this is the same reason for Ext.Anim.run not working. So could you please flesh out a bit how do i get a correct reference. Thanks for your time.

Comment: check the udpated code... I have provided code to show the details info when user tap on an item

Comment: wow! Thanks a lot! I've made it work but it is "var el = htmlElement.select('div.hidden');" in case if somebody needs this.